# Draw cirle to fit grid in xaml

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have this grid:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Background="#FF341616">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse                    
        Name="Red"
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Fill="#73b43c"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but when it scales, it distortes.

[image]

How can I fix it? I don't want to replace it with an image.

Comment: Have you tried a `Viewbox`?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Can you explain more about it? I've just try but the ellipse need hard code width and height.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last comment. Do you want the Width and Height to stay the same or do you want it to *scale* without distorting?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes, that it. Scale to fit the grid without distorting.

Comment: Then put the ellipse inside of a `<Viewbox></Viewbox>` and manually set the `Width` and `Height` of the `Ellipse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to scale without distorting, put it inside of a `Viewbox`:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Ellipse Name="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="#73b43c"/>
</Viewbox>
```

The `Stretch` property of the `Viewbox` can be set various values, depending on how you want the content to stretch. You probably want `Uniform`, which would look like this:

[image: Example]